# systemd reload networking

Tags: networking, systemd

I have found that the only way to reliably apply changes made to `/etc/network/interfaces` without instantly dropping my ssh connection (which is an issue if it is happening in the middle of an ansible script) is to run:

```
sudo service networking reload
```

How can I perform this equivalent using the 16.04 `systemd`?

Running:

```
sudo systemctl reload networking
```

Results in:

```
 Unable to reload service networking: Failed to reload
 networking.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit
 networking.service
```